# How to safely download and use Firebase admin SDK service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I’m coding a Firebase application.
The user can only read the database and the owner can write in the database to add some content.

The owner would need an admin desktop application to upload data on the database (storage and database).
Since the application is a C++ app I would use python to communicate with Firebase.

I wanted to use [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) or [python-firebase](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/) but unfortunately these projects seems not to support the new database Firestore…

The rest API could work but... only with the Firestore database part...

My only way to add content to Firestore and storage is then to use the admin sdk.

I know that the C++ applicaiton will be used only on the owner computer but I’m worried about getting the service account file.

What would be the best way to use safely the service account file?

I thought to:

1. Encrypt the file with a password and then ask the password every
   time the c++ needs to use the admin sdk (which technology would be
   better for this?)
2. Download the service account file everytime the app needs (but where
   to store it safely in the cloud?)

Comment: if you use google cloud functions you dont need the generate the service key file, if you are planning to use something else, any secret management tool would do the trick

Comment: What's an "owner" in your scenario? Because if they're a developer on the project, they can already access most resources through the Firebase console too.

Comment: @andresmijares It will be used into a desktop application so it's not a google cloud function unfortunately... What are the secret management tool you're talking about? I will be interested to know about it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The owner is my client. The purpose of this app is to let him set up some settings for a song (audio effect, lyrics and so on) when he's ok with them, he can upload them on Firebase Firestore and storage and all the users would be able to use this new settings.
Since he's a non tech guy it could be complicated for him to go on Firebase console download the json and so on... So I thought to embedded the service account in the app (used only by him) but better to be sure than cry I want to avoid any leak issues. So that's why I thougth to encrypt it or download it when needed.

Comment: if you think it works, it does, and it sounds like you already figured it out

Comment: @andresmijares I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you mean. In fact I don't know if it will work. I was wondering if it could be possible to download the service account elsewhere than the console app. I don't know the process to encrypt data with the technology you talked about. The second option to download it lead me here [Iam and service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-python) but I don't understand if it could help me since it's google cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the Admin SDK with a project, you must have access to the service account credentials for that project. And with those credentials, you have full and unlimited access to the project. You should only distribute the service account credentials to users who should have such access, typically the collaborators on the project.

For application level administrators that are not collaborators on the project, I typically recommend setting up an administrative dashboard with a server-side and a client-side component.

The *server-side component* runs in a trusted environment, which for me often is Cloud Functions, but can also be a server you control, or even your development machine. This is where you use the Admin SDK to perform application administration actions, which you then expose in an authenticated end-point that client-side applications can call.

The *client-side component* is what the application administrator uses. For me this is often a very simple web page, but it can also be any other technology you prefer, as long as it can call the end points you exposed on the server.

The key here is that the server validates that the user that calls it is authorized to do so, before executing administrative actions on their behalf. With this approach, you don't have to give the service account credentials to a non-collaborator, and can revoke the administrator's credentials if needed.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Indeed I din't think to use cloud function like this. I still need the desktop C++ app (audio processing stuff inside) but will call my custom Python function [using HTTP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) since it's a C++ app. This way the owner will still have to use id/password to call it and I won't need to share the service account. So no business issue if his computer is stolen or something else bad.